# Multiline regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for all the text that starts with the word "abc" and ends with a  ";". This text can span across multiple lines and can have space/tab in-between them.

I tried, `re.compile(r"""abc.+;""", re.DOTALL)`
It returns everying from the first occurance of "abc" to the last occurance of ";" as a single object. But I want the first "abc" to match to first ";" in first object, second "abc" to second ";" in second object and so on

I also tried, re.MULTILINE, it returns nothing.

None of the following worked:

`re.compile(r"""abc(.|\s)+;""", re.MULTILINE)`

`re.compile(r"""abc[.\s]+;""", re.MULTILINE)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use non-greedy modifier `abc.*?;` with flag DOTALL OR better use `abc[\w\W]*?;`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Can you please add it as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: This post already has a solution in the linked duplicate post, so can't add as answer and indeed not needed, but thanks for offering that. Glad I could help you :)